# How to merge rows in r based on a unique pairing of two variables?

Tags: r, join, dataframe, merge, dplyr

My apologies for the wonky title to the question. But I am having trouble figuring out this wrangling problem in R. Here is what a snippet of the data looks like:

```
example

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   id, rel [4]
     id        rel post_w      avg_w    b_wages   a_wages
  <int>     <date>  <lgl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2699 2005-12-05  FALSE   904.5028   904.5028        NA
2  2739 2008-02-12  FALSE  1220.8129  1220.8129        NA
3  2739 2008-02-12   TRUE  2544.8736         NA  2544.874
4  2757 2008-02-06   TRUE  2624.3018         NA  2624.302
5  3240 2005-03-30  FALSE 18718.6454 18718.6454        NA
6  3240 2005-03-30   TRUE 15206.3203         NA 15206.320
```

For my analysis the variables id and rel together create a unique identifier. I'm trying to have each unique id, rel combo to be one line containing a value for avg_w, b_wages, and a_wages. For example, in the data listed above, id 2739 and rel 2008-02-12 have two entries even though they are the same observation for my analysis. In one row the observation has data for b_wages and in the other it has data for a_wages. What I am trying to do is collapse those observations so that it would look like this

```
     id        rel post_w      avg_w    b_wages   a_wages
  <int>     <date>  <lgl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
2  2739 2008-02-12 (dropped)  (dropped)  1220.8129   2544.874
```

The columns post_w and avg_w are meaningless and I can drop them if necessary. But what I am trying to figure out is how I can collapse the rows which have the same id, rel to one row and merge the b_wages and a_wages values together, replacing the NA values as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your data frame by *id* and *rel*, and then summarize it by taking the first non NA value; Caveats are if there are more than one non NA values, this will take the first one and drop others:

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% 
    group_by(id, rel) %>% 
    summarise(b_wages = na.omit(b_wages)[1], 
              a_wages = na.omit(a_wages)[1])

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id [?]
#     id        rel    b_wages   a_wages
#  <int>     <fctr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  2699 2005-12-05   904.5028        NA
#2  2739 2008-02-12  1220.8129  2544.874
#3  2757 2008-02-06         NA  2624.302
#4  3240 2005-03-30 18718.6454 15206.320
```

Comment: I tried your method here and it worked perfectly! thanks so much!